Imputador propio no funciona en Pipeline de PySpark
Estoy usando PySpark y he creado mi propia clase de Imputador de la siguiente forma:
class CustomImputer(Estimator):
    def __init__(self, inputCol, outputCol, strategy, group_column, impute_character=None):
        super(CustomImputer, self).__init__()
        ....

    def _fit(self, data):
        ....
  
    def transform(self, new_data):
        ....

Luego lo uso en un Pipeline entrenando haciendo Cross validation pero recibo este error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 13
     10 #tvs = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=params, trainRatio=0.7)
     11 cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, evaluator=evaluator, estimatorParamMaps=params, numFolds=3)
---> 13 trained_cv = cv.fit(train)
     14 best_lr = trained_cv.bestModel

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py:205, in Estimator.fit(self, dataset, params)
    203         return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    204     else:
--> 205         return self._fit(dataset)
    206 else:
    207     raise TypeError(
    208         "Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "
    209         "but got %s." % type(params)
    210     )

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py:847, in CrossValidator._fit(self, dataset)
    841 train = datasets[i][0].cache()
    843 tasks = map(
    844     inheritable_thread_target,
    845     _parallelFitTasks(est, train, eva, validation, epm, collectSubModelsParam),
    846 )
--> 847 for j, metric, subModel in pool.imap_unordered(lambda f: f(), tasks):
    848     metrics_all[i][j] = metric
    849     if collectSubModelsParam:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py:873, in IMapIterator.next(self, timeout)
    871 if success:
    872     return value
--> 873 raise value

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py:125, in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
    123 job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    124 try:
--> 125     result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    126 except Exception as e:
    127     if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py:847, in CrossValidator._fit.<locals>.<lambda>(f)
    841 train = datasets[i][0].cache()
    843 tasks = map(
    844     inheritable_thread_target,
    845     _parallelFitTasks(est, train, eva, validation, epm, collectSubModelsParam),
    846 )
--> 847 for j, metric, subModel in pool.imap_unordered(lambda f: f(), tasks):
    848     metrics_all[i][j] = metric
    849     if collectSubModelsParam:

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/util.py:342, in inheritable_thread_target.<locals>.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    340 assert SparkContext._active_spark_context is not None
    341 SparkContext._active_spark_context._jsc.sc().setLocalProperties(properties)
--> 342 return f(*args, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py:118, in _parallelFitTasks.<locals>.singleTask()
    113 index, model = next(modelIter)
    114 # TODO: duplicate evaluator to take extra params from input
    115 #  Note: Supporting tuning params in evaluator need update method
    116 #  `MetaAlgorithmReadWrite.getAllNestedStages`, make it return
    117 #  all nested stages and evaluators
--> 118 metric = eva.evaluate(model.transform(validation, epm[index]))
    119 return index, metric, model if collectSubModel else None

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/evaluation.py:111, in Evaluator.evaluate(self, dataset, params)
    109         return self.copy(params)._evaluate(dataset)
    110     else:
--> 111         return self._evaluate(dataset)
    112 else:
    113     raise TypeError("Params must be a param map but got %s." % type(params))

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/evaluation.py:148, in JavaEvaluator._evaluate(self, dataset)
    146 self._transfer_params_to_java()
    147 assert self._java_obj is not None
--> 148 return self._java_obj.evaluate(dataset._jdf)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1856.evaluate.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 486.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 486.0 (TID 1945) (813302be1d05 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (`VectorAssembler$$Lambda$4596/0x00000040021625c0`: (struct<familiarity_imputed:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>).
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1(VectorAssembler.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1$adapted(VectorAssembler.scala:260)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.$anonfun$transform$6(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
    ... 22 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2463)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1045)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner$.sketch(Partitioner.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner.<init>(Partitioner.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner.<init>(Partitioner.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions.$anonfun$sortByKey$1(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions.sortByKey(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.x$3$lzycompute(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.x$3(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.confusions$lzycompute(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.confusions(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.createCurve(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.roc(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.areaUnderROC(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator.evaluate(BinaryClassificationEvaluator.scala:101)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (`VectorAssembler$$Lambda$4596/0x00000040021625c0`: (struct<familiarity_imputed:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>).
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1(VectorAssembler.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.$anonfun$assemble$1$adapted(VectorAssembler.scala:260)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$.assemble(VectorAssembler.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.$anonfun$transform$6(VectorAssembler.scala:143)
    ... 22 more

Me he dado cuenta de esta parte del error:
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered null while assembling a row with handleInvalid = "error". Consider
removing nulls from dataset or using handleInvalid = "keep" or "skip".

He comprobado que el resultado tras aplicar el pipeline es correcto y no tengo valores nulos. La cosa es que cuando quito las nuevas columnas que se me generan al usar el transform() de mi imputador, no me da problema el pipeline.
¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar ocurriendo y si he creado de forma correcta mi clase Imputador?
